# Light Baking Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

Before I have real-time lighting because of the performance issue, I decided to do light baking for my 3d game.

So I have mark 3d environment as static because it remains on screen always without movement.
Also changed direction light mode to Mixed because I have few moving game objects too.

But after the baking process gets completed, I got this kind of output:
[image]

In above, you can see in the above image what happened with my environment after baking and I have also included light settings if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable lightmap UVs in your 3d imported model file.

[image]

I got this reply from one Unity forum member so exact wording, I am posting here:
[image]